# Filtering data in the data modeler

Tags: excel, vba, filtering, pivot-table, datamodel

I have a sheet with many pivot tables connecting to the data modeller. The source data is based off a range in another worksheet. The reason I am using the data modeller is because I am trying to utilize it's Distinct Count feature.

What I am trying to do is to filter all of my pivot tables in one swoop. I tried this through VBA (see code below), but I can't as too many lines are produced and the code bugs out. The idea is to filter out any data with a time to cancellation under 30.

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
            pt.PivotFields("[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation]_
            .[Time Till Cancellation]").VisibleItemsList _
            = Array("[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[31]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[32]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[33]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[34]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[35]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[36]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[37]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[38]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[39]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[40]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[41]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[42]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[43]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[44]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[45]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[46]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[47]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[48]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[49]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[50]", _
    "[Range1].[Time Till Cancellation].&[51]", _ (...and so on up to 150)
```

My question is -

Can I do this on through a feature within the data modeller ie some type of SELECT WHERE statement; or

Is there an easier way to write this in VBA so I do not have too many lines of code (and yes, I could concatenate these lines into one single line but I am just wondering if there was an cleaner way)

Many thanks,

Chris

Comment: Interesting question. +1. I have no idea, but I'm curious to see the answer.